# How to make OpenCV work fully on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have managed to install OpenCV on my raspberry pi, but I have an issue when I would like to use it. Every time I want to run a python script that uses OpenCV, I have to add the following command in the terminal every time.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 python3 some_script.py
```

This makes the code run and successfully use OpenCV, but however, it is far from ideal. 
Does anyone know any good solution for this?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment, a conda environment, or something similar?

Comment: You could try to set this variable in your bash profile `echo 'export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1' >> ~/.profile`. This will make it so that you don't have to type it all the time in your terminal.  Or you could export the environment variable before importing open CV in python using sys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `LD_PRELOAD` to load that file before any other library. You can export the variable to your runtime with:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1
```

Then execute the python script as normal.

```
python3 some_script.py
```

To make the variable persist across terminal sessions, put it in `$HOME/.bashrc`